Base to Derived static_cast, not visible relation
We can static_cast from Base* to Derived*, but in my case the relationship is not visible when the cast is supposed to happen. Is there any trick (besides of reinterpret_cast of course) to make it work?
struct Derived;

struct Base 
{
    Base()
    {
        //Is there a way to make it work?
        //Derived* d = static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
};

int main()
{
    Base b{};
    // Here it works as the compiler is aware of the relationship
    Derived* d = static_cast<Derived*>(&b);
}

You can try it here.
Update:
Thanks for your comments. Of course, I know that my example code is broken, I just wanted to demonstrate the problem. The real world problem is much more complex.
I have an opaque pointer that points to either Base or Derived (compile time switch). And I need that opaque pointer in the constructor of the Base class. When the opaque pointer is Derived* then Base cannot be instantiated just through Derived, so it is 100% safe. In the other case Base == Derived so no cast would happen.
As it is an opaque pointer and we are in Base, we have only a forward declaration of Derived. Like:
#ifdef PLATFORM_A
    typedef struct Derived UsedType;
#else
    typedef struct Base UsedType;
#endif

So I would need an UsedType* in the Base constructor, the virtual this is either Base* or Derived*. Unfortunately if we are not on PLATFORM_A then Derived is not defined at all, so when the code reaches Base's constructor the compiler cannot know about it's relation with Derived (as Derived might not exist at all, and in that case the cast is from Base* to Base*).
Update 2: Real world code
Update 3: I updated the code once more. Now there is a member that stores the opaque this pointer. I don't use it in the constructor, I use it only outside. It needs to be initialized in the constructor (as the member is const).
#include <iostream>

#define PLATFORM_A

#ifdef PLATFORM_A
    typedef struct Derived UsedType;
#else
    typedef struct Base UsedType;
#endif

struct User 
{
    UsedType* const platform;
    void print() const;
};

struct Base 
{
    const char* const name{"Base"};
    User const iNeedThis;
#ifdef PLATFORM_A
  protected:
#endif
    Base()
      : iNeedThis{(UsedType*)this}
      //: iNeedThis{static_cast<UsedType*>(this)}
    {
    }
};

#ifdef PLATFORM_A
  struct Derived: public Base
  {
    const char* const name{"Derived"};
    Derived()
      : Base()
    {
    }
  };
#endif

void User::print() const
{
    std::cout << platform->name << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    UsedType myObj{};
    myObj.iNeedThis.print();
}

https://godbolt.org/z/sMr5Kfxrn

Side note, it should hardly ever be needed to cast an object to a derived class. Why do you think you need it?

Do you have a real world use case where you'd need to access the Derived* within Base constructor?  Or is this just a thought experiment?

There is no way to use *this as a Derived full stop. because the object residing at this is not a Derived so any access to it as Derived would be Undefined Behavior and no cast can change that, static_cast or reinterpret_cast or unobtainable_cast.

I don't know what the larger context is. However, this somewhat reminds me of the curiously recurring template pattern Perhaps you should look into that. Otherwise, this feels like a design problem on a higher level to me.

@AviBerger yes, I was thinking on CRTP but I can't move Base's constructor to the header :( Yeah, it is a kind of design problem, but that Base to Derived cast could solve it. But seemingly I need to think about a plan B :)

Force delayed evaluation by templating the Base constructor. template<typename T = Derived> Base() { static_cast<T*>(this); }

@Broothy How is UsedType related to the Base constructor? Please [edit] your question to provide a better example of the ACTUAL PROBLEM you are having with it.

@RemyLebeau sure. please find the real world code in the second update.

@Broothy as stated earlier, when PLATFORM_A is defined and thus UsedType is Derived, then UsedType* iNeedThis = static_cast<UsedType*>(this); will cause Undefined Behavior if you try to dereference iNeedThis. It is still not clear WHY you need this casted pointer in the first place. What is the Base constructor going to do with this pointer exactly? I'm starting to wonder if this is actually an XY Problem instead.

@RemyLebeau At that point the constructor pass iNeedThis to a member. It is handled as an opaque pointer, so it is not dereferenced in the constructor. I could set it outside the constructor, but it would be error prone. I think the sample code is complete, but it is completely possible that it cannot be solved this way.

@Broothy Even if you just save the pointer, I think it is still UB inside of the Base constructor since there is no Derived object yet for this to point at. Why can't you just cast this later on?  Why does it need to be casted inside the constructor? This is NOT a [mcve] (where is the member? How is the member used?, etc)

Any particular reason you're not doing whatever it is you need to do polymorphically using something virtual?

@RemyLebeau I added the member as you wished. I need it to be initialized in the constructor as the member storing it is const. In the constructor it is handled as an opaque pointer, at that point we don't know much about the type anyway, just typedef struct Derived UsedType; if PLATFORM_A is defined.

I mean, it's trivial to do literally what you asked, even without moving the constructor:
struct Base 
{
  UsedType* self();

#ifdef PLATFORM_A
  protected:
#endif
    Base()
    {
        UsedType* iNeedThis = self();
    }
};

Later on, in base.cpp or wherever:
#ifndef PLATFORM_A
  UsedType* Base::self() { return this; }
#endif

and even later on, in derived.cpp
#ifdef PLATFORM_A
UsedType* Base::self()
{
  return static_cast<Derived*>(this);
}
#endif

But it still seems like a bad design.

Aaaa great, I was thinking about a trick like this, thx!

It is a bad design, but trying to add support to a second, completely different platform to a codebase that was not designed to be multiplatform without a full rewrite requires such bad design decisions...

To answer your question - you can't cast to an incomplete type, so you would need to move the implementation of Base() after the declaration of Derived, eg:
struct Derived;

struct Base 
{
    Base();
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
};

Base::Base()
{
    // see note below!!!
    Derived* d = static_cast<Derived*>(this);
}

int main()
{
    Base b{};
    // see note below!!!
    Derived* d = static_cast<Derived*>(&b);
}

That being said, what you are doing is risky, because this inside of the Base constructor is not pointing at a Derived object, and b inside of main() is not a Derived object either.  If you try to dereference the casted pointer in either situation, you will invoke undefined behavior.
There is no way to make the cast inside of the Base constructor be legal, since any Derived object would simply not exist yet while the Base class is being constructed.
But, in main(), you can change b to be a pointer to a Derived object, then you can safely cast that pointer, eg:
int main()
{
    Derived obj{};
    Base* b = &obj;

    // this is perfectly OK!
    Derived* d = static_cast<Derived*>(b);
}


Hi, thx for your suggestion. Unfortunately I cannot move Base's constructor to the point where Derived is visible, please see the update in the description. It would be possible (in theory) to have a templated constructor that receives the 'real' Derived pointer from Derived's constructor when it calls Base, but unfortunately I cannot move the constructor to the header, so it cannot be templated.

Thank you for your suggestion, but it unfortunately it isn't doable in my specific case. The other answer solves my special case as well.
